# how to use FacesContext in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf

how to use FacesContext in JSF? please give me one whole example ? and some explantion when and at what condition we need to use this?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/213954/JSF/java/Facescontext-Context-Object

Comment: Don't use it just because you *must* do. Only use it whenever you *need* it. You will encounter the need automagically yourself sooner or later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FacesContext` gives you access to multiple useful contexts and objects, like:

- the `Application` object, containing application-related 'settings'
- the external context, which is in most cases the `ServletContext`
- Various JSF UI objects, like the render kit, the `UIViewRoot`

You obtain it via `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`. After that - check [the docs](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html) to see what can be of particular interest to you.

The `FacesContext` is initialized per each request, and `getCurrentInstance()` actually returns a `ThreadLocal` variable.

It is to be noted, that a simple application should be able to work without the need to access the `FacesContext`.

Comment: @vinod np. If an answer works for you, you can mark it as accepted (tick below the vote counter)